# Use finch in application delegate?

Tags: ios, finch

I am finalizing a ipad game and Finch seems really nice to handle game sounds ... 
My question is : is it possible to instantiate all the finch mechanism in the Application Delegate and to use it from the multiple game screens ?
I mean prepare finch sounds in delegates and launch them from game screens ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Finch mechanism but all I can say in general is that the application delegate is not the place to do this. What I would advise you to do is create a "SoundEngine" singleton class (you could instantiate this once the application launches in the application delegate). Hook this sound engine to the Finch framework and create public convenience methods to play sounds - because this is a Singleton, it is safe to use and accessible from the whole application and is very convenient to access.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I installed Finch in an indeptendat Workspace in side my project.
Starting to implement the Singleton and I've got strange errors on the below code

```
#import "FinchSoundManager.h"
#import "FISoundEngine.h"
#import "FIFactory.h"


@implementation FinchSoundManager
static FinchSoundManager *sharedInstance = nil;

@synthesize soundEngine,soundFactory;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    soundFactory = [[FIFactory alloc] init];
    [soundFactory setLogger:FILoggerNSLog];

    [self setSoundEngine:[soundFactory buildSoundEngine]];
    [soundEngine activateAudioSessionWithCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback];
    [soundEngine openAudioDevice];

}

return self;
}
```

1) error on AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback -> use of unidentified identifier
2) in finch itself : FISoundEngine:  "Unknown Type Name AVAudioSession" 
    #import "FILogger.h"

```
@interface FISoundEngine : NSObject

@property(copy) FILogger logger;
@property(readonly) BOOL isRunning;
@property(strong) AVAudioSession *audioSession;

- (BOOL) activateAudioSessionWithCategory: (NSString*) categoryName;
- (void) deactivateAudioSession;

- (BOOL) openAudioDevice;
- (void) closeAudioDevice;

@end
```

Can't understand where the error on FISoundEngine since it was simply imported in my project ... any clue ?